# missing data in popen call

Tags: c++, popen

my program compiles without error  and appears to run through all of the steps correctly. It is supposed to make a php call and return data. tcpdump does show the request going out so popen is being executed, but the receiving party never updates.
The only discrepancy I can find, is that the command variable appears to be missing data.

# .trol.o

```
market max price is 0.00638671 at position 0
php coin.php 155 0.006387
0.00638672
```

the second line in the output is the command I am sending to popen

```
cout << command << endl; ->  php coin.php 155 0.006387
```

that number is supposed to be the same as the one under it  0.00638672
The number 6 and the number 2 have been chopped off somehow.

How do I get the correct data into my popen command?

code:

```
void mngr(){
        //vector defs
        vector<std::string> buydat;
        vector<std::string> markdat;
        vector<std::string> pricedat;
        vector<std::string> purchaseid;
        vector<double> doublePdat;
        vector<double> doubleMdat;
        doublePdat.reserve(pricedat.size());
        doubleMdat.reserve(markdat.size());
        char buybuff[BUFSIZ];
        char command[70];
        char sendbuy[12];
        buydat = getmyData();
        markdat = getmarketbuyData();
        //string match "Buy" and send results to new vector with pricedat.push_back()
        for(int b = 2; b < buydat.size(); b+=7){
                if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ) {
                         pricedat.push_back(buydat[b+1]);
                }
        }
        transform(pricedat.begin(), pricedat.end(), back_inserter(doublePdat), [](string const& val) {return stod(val);});
        transform(markdat.begin(), markdat.end(), back_inserter(doubleMdat), [](string const& val) {return stod(val);});
        auto biggestMy = std::max_element(std::begin(doublePdat), std::end(doublePdat));
        std::cout << "my max price is " << *biggestMy << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(doublePdat), biggestMy) << std::endl;
        auto biggestMark = std::max_element(std::begin(doubleMdat), std::end(doubleMdat));
        std::cout << "market max price is " << *biggestMark << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(doubleMdat), biggestMark) << std::endl;
        if (biggestMy > biggestMark){
                cout << "Biggest is Mine!" << endl;
        }
        else if (biggestMy < biggestMark){
                //cout << "Biggest is market!";
                *biggestMark += 0.00000001;
                sprintf(sendbuy,"%f",*biggestMark);
                sprintf(command, "php coin.php 155 %s",sendbuy);
                FILE *markbuy = popen(command, "r");
                if (markbuy == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
                while(fgets(buybuff, sizeof(buybuff), markbuy) != NULL){
                        size_t h = strlen(buybuff);
                        //clean '\0' from fgets
                        if (h && buybuff[h - 1] == '\n') buybuff[h - 1] = '\0';
                        if (buybuff[0] != '\0') purchaseid.push_back(buybuff);
                }

                cout << command << endl;
                cout << *biggestMark << endl;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use long float format instead of float as the type of biggestMark should be evaluated as iterator across doubles. I mean try to change `sprintf(sendbuy,"%f",*biggestMark);` to `sprintf(sendbuy,"%lf",*biggestMark);`. Hope this would help.

Comment: That did improve things. Instead of dropping incrementally, it just ate the last 2 neatly. But still missing the last 2 digits.  :(  my max price is 0.00521413 at position 2
market max price is 0.00642538 at position 0
/usr/bin/php /home/coinz/coin.php 155 0.006425
0.00642539

Comment: Is not this related to the limitation of floating point representation that IEEE 754 standard has? In particular performing `*biggestMark += 1E-8` is kind of tricky thing to do with floating point numbers. Try to avoid such statements in the code.

Comment: same results with *biggestMark = *biggestMark + 0.00000001;